# C++ empty while loop optimization behaves differently with global vs local variable used in loop condition

Tags: c++

The code in this post is an example from CppCon2023 - Fedor Pikus's talk on UB. Unfortunately, the speaker does not explain this specific behavior in their talk - this knowledge is presumed to be common among the attendees, but I am sadly missing it...

The following code, compiled with -O3 using either clang or gcc (various versions tried in Compiler Explorer), exhibits different behavior if `int i` is global vs local to `main`. Specifically, the empty loop is eliminated if `int i` is global, but kept if it's local.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int i = 1;
int main() {
    std::cout << "Before infinite loop" << std::endl;
    while (i) {}
    std::cout << "After infinite loop.... wat?" << std::endl;
}
```

I understand, based on the above-referenced talk, and similar questions on StackOverflow, that the empty loop is UB, and can be eliminated by the compiler; I do not understand (and can't find any info on the subject) *why the behavior differs based on scope of `int i`*.

Why does it matter in this case where `int i` is defined?

Comment: The behavior of this **program** is undefined; the compiler is free to do anything at all. There's nothing further to say.

Comment: Am I overlooking something or isn’t it that when `i` is a global variable, it could be potentially modified by `std::cout`? Thus, if `std::cout` doesn’t touch `i`, there is an infinite loop (UB), so the compiler assumes that there cannot be UB, hence, `std::cout` must set `i` to 0. Whereas when I is local, `std::cout` cannot  know about it and hence cannot change it, so the compiler sees that the UB is inevitable - there is no other path. Still, why not eliminate the loop anyway? Maybe, because that would be less intuitive… idk. As the programmer expects the program to hang, even though its UB

Comment: Few compilers (in practice, almost certainly no compilers) will do enough analysis (or be hard-coded with enough assumptions) to spot that the operations on `std::cout` do not modify a global/static named `i`.  When `i` is of automatic storage duration (and no reference or pointer to it is passed anywhere) it is (relatively) easier for a compiler to do enough analysis to recognise that `i` will not be modified, conclude that the loop has undefined behaviour, and [if that's what the compiler does when it identifies a case of UB] eliminate the loop.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in my post somehow - the loop is eliminated *if `int i` is **global**, and kept if it's local*

Comment: Don't care.   The behaviour is undefined.   A compiler is permitted to do anything it likes, regardless of whether that makes sense or not to a programmer.   And, in practice, a lot of compilers (which are complicated systems) do things that are counter-intuitive to programmers.  When behaviour is undefined, it is the programmer who needs to let go of their assumption, not the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the behavior differs based on scope of int i

The program as such has undefined behavior in either case because of the infinite loop without atomic/volatile/IO/synchronization operation. Therefore both eliminating the loop, keeping the loop or doing anything else is valid regardless of `i`'s scope.

---

Some guesses on the lack of optimization with global scope:

While compiling the `main` function, at least assuming LTO isn't used, the compiler doesn't know yet that this is the whole program. There could be other translation units.

Such a unit could look like this:

```
extern int i;
int j = (i=0);
```

Because `i` has constant initialization, the initialization is guaranteed to happen before `j`'s initialization and if the implementation makes the implementation-defined choice to do dynamic initialization before `main` is entered, then the resulting value of `i` in the loop will be `0`, not `1`.

So, generally compilers can't make assumptions about the value of global variables in `main`, even if the initializer is seen in the same translation unit.

And aside from that, compilers don't have enough information to know that the output line before the loop doesn't modify the global either. But I don't expect the result to change without the diagnostic output for the reasons mentioned above.

Therefore the compiler will likely treat `i` as having an unknown value in the loop. It is then probably a short-coming of the optimizer to not recognize that eliminating the loop is correct in all cases: Either `i` is `0` and the loop is never entered, or the loop is infinite and has UB.

---

It seems I misread that. If the optimization does happen at global scope, then the optimizer is probably clever enough to recognize the possible outcomes I mentioned above.

A missing optimization with local scope could be for the same reason if the value of `i` is written before the output statement.

However, especially if it is placed immediately before the loop, then I expect the non-removal of the loop to be an intentional choice by the compiler writers.

Many users of C++ (and C) assume that they can use infinite loops like that to keep a thread waiting indefinitely. In C this is even possible if the loop condition is an integral constant (which it is not in your case). But in C++ even that is not allowed. So I am pretty sure that they at least intentionally don't optimize loops of the form `while(1);`. Either your form is intentionally not optimized as well or a result of constant-propagation into that form.

Comment: Interestingly, the optimization happens on global scope (as I mentioned in my post) - but not on local scope - which is what I find very strange. Also, enabling LTO via either -flto or using -fwhole-program (gcc) flags does not change the behavior

Comment: @CoolBots Oh sorry, I misread that. If that is the case, then it could still be due to the output statement inbetween. If it also doesn't do the optimization if `int i = 1;` is immediately before the loop, then I would guess that the optimization is intentionally not done for the specific constellation. Users may not be aware of the forward-progress rules and assume that loops of this form can be used to keep a thread waiting. I am pretty sure GCC at least intentionally doesn't do it for `while(1) { };` because that is only UB in C++, not C. (Your case is UB in both.)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the behavior is *not defined* irrelevant of where `i` is defined. Note that reasoning about undefined behavior is like reading tea leaves or crystal gazing or telling bedtime stories. Your question is:

> why the [actual produced] behavior differs based on scope of int i.

Because GCC is not able to prove that `i` will not be changed before the loop and you are not using LTO or whole-program optimization. Consider `edit.cpp`:

```
extern int i;
struct Edit {
    Edit() {
        i = 0;
    }
};
Edit edit{};
```

Compiling:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c edit.cpp
g++ main.o edit.o
```

It is impossible to know at `g++ -c main.cpp` that the loop will be executed or not, so it is not optimized out. In contrast:

```
g++ -O2 -fwhole-program main.cpp
```

Will optimize the loop out, because `g++` knows it is the whole program.

Comment: I generally agree that UB is well... UB. I find it strange that the compiler behaves differently in this case based on scope; I also find it strange that it's the locally defined variable that causes the loop to be kept (as I stated in my original post) - the compiler has full knowledge of that variable, LTO or not. Furthermore, enabling LTO via either -flto or using -fwhole-program (gcc) flags does not appear to change the behavior.

Comment: You're assuming there is some master logic in the compiler that decides to optimise one way when your variable is global, and another way when it is local.  There (usually) is not.  Compiler optimisation usually involves a large set of simple micro-optimisation steps with some complicated orchestrating logic to feed output from some steps as input to other steps.  The emergent property (different behaviour based on local or global variable) is usually not done deliberately - it is a side effect of controlling logic.